# Ender 3 motor cable not working

Tags: motor, wiring

I had my Ender 3 packed away for the past two years while I was traveling. I came back and reassembled it, but there is no movement from certain motors/wires. I swapped some of the cables around and the x and z axis cables work fine on all motors. Meanwhile, the Y axis cable only works in one direction, and the extruder cable doesn’t work at all. Could it be due to a faulty cable, or is it on the firmware side? And what fixes could there be?